# Cannot read property of undefined when calling method as a callback

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to OOP and angular.
currently, I want to use reusable table with pagination that makes a request API if page change (pagination inside table component).

the problem is when I access my method using callback from table component (Child) I got undefined.

but when I try to move pagination to MasterGudang (Parent) Components it's work.

I don't really understand what's going on.
**Error undefined**
[image]

but here some code.

**table.component.ts**

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-table-custom',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() items: any;
  @Input() callback: any;
  @Input() columns: [];
  p: number = 1;

  @ContentChild('action', { static: false }) actionRef: TemplateRef<any>;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = new Subject();
    this.items.next();
  }

  onChangePage = (evt) => {
    this.callback()
  }
```

**Gudang.component.ts**

```
import { MasterGudangService } from '../../../../@core/services/master-service/menu-gudang/gudang/masterGudang.service';

@Component({
  selector: "ngx-gudang",
  templateUrl: './gudang.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gudang.component.scss'],
})

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GudangComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public masterGudangService: MasterGudangService
    ) {
      console.log(masterGudangService)
    }

  tableData: [];
  isEdit: boolean = false;

  currentPage: number = 1;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getList();
  }

  getList (page?: number) {
    this.masterGudangService.getPgb(page? page: this.currentPage).subscribe(response => {
      const { data: { content, totalElements, size, number } } = response;
      this.tableData = Object.assign({
        data: content,
        total: totalElements,
        size: size,
        number: number
      });
    });
  }
}
```

And here I passing my function which is getList to table component

**gudang.component.html**

```
 <ngx-table-custom [callback]="getList" [columns]="column" [items]="tableData">
      <ng-template let-item #action>
        <div class="row">
          <button nbButton status="success" (click)="open(dialog, item, true)" class="mx-2" size="tiny"><nb-icon icon="edit"></nb-icon></button>
          <button nbButton status="danger" (click)="onDelete(item)" size="tiny"><nb-icon icon="trash"></nb-icon></button>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-table-custom>
```

**MasterGudangService.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MasterGudangService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPgb (page: number = 1, perPage: number = 10) :any {
    return this.http.get(`my-api-url/pgb?page=${page}&size=${perPage}`)
  }
}
```

**table.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <table class="table table-md table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr style="background-color: #3366ff; color: #fff;">
        <th *ngFor="let column of columns" class="text-basic">{{ column.value }}</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of items.data | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: items.total }; index as idx;">
        <td *ngFor="let column of columns">
          <div *ngIf="column.key === 'number';"><b class="text-basic">{{ idx + 1 }}</b></div>
          <div *ngIf="column.key !== 'action' && !isNested(column.key);" class="text-basic">{{ item[column.key] }}</div>
          <div *ngIf="isNested(column.key);" class="text-basic">{{ getKeys(item, column.key) }}</div>
          <!-- <div *ngIf="column.key === 'action; action_container"></div> -->
            <ng-template [ngIf]="column.key === 'action'" #action_content>
              <ng-container
              *ngIf="actionRef"
              [ngTemplateOutlet]="actionRef"
              [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit:item}">
            </ng-container>
          </ng-template>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12" align="center">
    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="onChangePage($event)"></pagination-controls>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `MasterGudangService` can you show the code within this service?

Comment: @marcusshep edited my post, sorry i forgot to bring MasterGudangService

Comment: i think you need to bind your callback to `this`

Comment: The problem is that when the table calls the callback `this` refers to something different.  Essentially, you are losing your context.  You can try using [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to create a function that retains it's context.

Comment: I've try `this.callback.bind(this)` and `this.callback.bind(evt)`, still not work but error gone. @BizzyBob

Comment: Please share Table Component HTML. The error originates in there

Comment: @T.SunilRao ya I already edit my post, you can take a look

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @SyahrizalSetiawan `this.getList = this.getList.bind(this);`

Comment: **this.getList = this.getList.bind(this);** Where I should put this code? @JaredSmith

Answer (score 0):

The context of Gudang.component.ts will not be available using callback from table component.

The proper way to implement should be passing the event instead of passing function for callback

**table.component.ts**

```
@Output() pageChange = new EventEmitter()
onChangePage = (evt) => {
   this.pageChange.emit(evt);
}
```

**gudang.component.html**

```
<ngx-table-custom (pageChange)="getList($event)" [columns]="column" [items]="tableData">
    ...
</ngx-table-custom>
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the error, it seems like masterGudangService is null at the time you are trying to access it. Adding this code might help you eliminate the error and at least debug what is going on and get a step further.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  if(this.masterGudangService)
    this.getList();
  else
    console.log('service not defined!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a helper Method in GudangComponent

```
getListCallback() {
  return this.getList.bind(this);
}
```

and use it here

```
<ngx-table-custom [callback]="getListCallback()" [columns]="column" [items]="tableData">
```